# iostream: No such file or directory in Android NDK Environment

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I compiled the *.cpp file on Android NDK Environment.
But, I was saw this messgage.

```
dohyeon@ubuntu:/opt/android-ndk-r9d/jni$ ../ndk-build
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: CPPTETRIS <= main.cpp
/opt/android-ndk-r9d/jni/main.cpp:3:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/opt/android-ndk-r9d/obj/local/armeabi/objs/CPPTETRIS/main.o] Error 1
dohyeon@ubuntu:/opt/android-ndk-r9d/jni$
```

My c++ files name are main.cpp and plane.cpp.

My Andorid.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_STL := stlport_static

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := CPPTETRIS
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp plane.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include-all

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

I wonder why do this.
Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

In my case APP_STL definition should be in the ./jni/**Application.mk** file and not in the Android.mk file.

Comment: That should be the solution - to quote the documentation "IMPORTANT: Defining APP_STL in Android.mk has no effect!"

Answer (score -1):

```
try this code..

static {
        System.loadLibrary("CPPTETRIS");
    }
```

add this above lines to your activity above oncreate method..

```
followed by your jni in android.mk file.. and also add android tools add nativetools.
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
APP_OPTIM    := debug
ndk-build APP_ABI=x86 NDK_DEBUG=1

LOCAL_MODULE    := CPPTETRIS
LOCAL_CFLAGS = -DFIXED_POINT -DUSE_KISS_FFT -DEXPORT="" -UHAVE_CONFIG_H
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
./libspeex/bits.c \
./yourcppfilename.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```